# Компиляция списка файлов с разными опциями

Tags: makefile

Есть несколько `*.dot` файлов и я делаю из них изображения графов. Пара графов требуют специальных опций, а остальные преобразуются одной шаблонной командой.

*Makefile:*

```
DOTS = ex1.dot ex2.dot ex4.dot
IMGS = $(DOTS:.dot=.png)

all: ex1.png ex2.png ex3.png ex4.png

ex1.png: ex1.dot
    dot -Tpng -o ex1.png ex1.dot

ex2.png: ex2.dot
    dot -Tpng -o ex2.png ex2.dot

ex3.png: ex3.dot
    dot -Kfdp -n -Tpng -o ex3.png ex3.dot

ex4.png: ex4.dot
    dot -Tpng -o ex4.png ex4.dot

...
```

И тут ситуация может меняться. Какие-то `.dot` файлы могут потребовать вдруг особой опции, какие-то может оказаться не нужно преобразовывать. Не хотелось бы снова и снова писать и удалять цели, а хотелось бы просто поменять пару переменных.

P.S. Может посоветуете другой инструмент (желательно программируемый как, например, *SCons*)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я немного абстрагирую названия файлов, чтобы все эти `dot/png` не сбивали с толку.

итак, у нас есть файлы `a1.src a2.src a3.src a4.src`, и надо их (известным образом) преобразовать в `a1.res a2.res a3.res a4.res`.

для начала — перечислим исходные файлы:

```
srcs=a1.src a2.src a3.src a4.src
```

и автоматически сгенерируем из них список файлов-результатов, заменив суффикс `.src` на `.res`:

```
results=$(srcs:.src=.res)
```

первая из целей (слово `all` в качестве первой цели — просто дань традиции, можно использовать произвольное имя) указывает, что для её выполнения нужно «собрать» `a1.res a2.res a3.res a4.res` (этот список у нас хранится в переменной `$(results)`:

```
all: $(results)
```

а дальше нужно правило для «сборки» файла `*.res` из «одноимённого» файла `*.src`:

```
%.res: %.src
```

ниже правила указываем «рецепт» по сборке (здесь приведён фиктивный рецепт, который просто печатает на экран строку, в реальности надо будет вписать подходящую команду):

```
  @echo 'собираем $@ из $<'
```

---

получился такой файл:

```
srcs=a1.src a2.src a3.src a4.src
results=$(srcs:.src=.res)
all: $(results)
%.res: %.src
  @echo 'собираем $@ из $<'
```

проверяем, интерпретируя его программой *make*:

```
$ make
собираем a1.res из a1.src
собираем a2.res из a2.src
собираем a3.res из a3.src
собираем a4.res из a4.src
```

#### а как бы теперь одну из команд, например, для «сборки» `a3.res`, заменить на что-нибудь другое?

элементарно — надо добавить ещё одно правило. именно для этой цели (`a3.res`):

```
a3.res: a3.src
  @echo 'собираем $@ из $< по-особому'
```

теперь результат выполнения программы *make* будет чуть иной:

```
$ make
собираем a1.res из a1.src
собираем a2.res из a2.src
собираем a3.res из a3.src по-особому
собираем a4.res из a4.src
```

#### а если так же, «по-особому», надо «собрать» и, например, `a2.res`?

надо добавить ещё одно правило. именно для этой цели (`a2.res`):

```
a2.res: a2.src
  @echo 'собираем $@ из $< по-особому'
```

#### но у нас получается дублирование: для целей `a2.res` и `a3.res` — один и тот же рецепт. можно ли обойтись без дублирования?

можно, конечно. но придётся применить «немного уличной магии».

во-первых, чуть перепишем «универсальное» правило «сборки» (убрав дополнительные, для `a2.res` и `a3.res`), добавив в него подстановку пока не определённой переменной (например, `$(subs)`):

```
%.res: %.src
  @echo 'собираем $@ из $< $(subs)'
```

во-вторых, добавим список целей, которые должны быть собраны «по-особому»:

```
list=a2.res a3.res
```

а в-третьих, напишем реализацию «магической» переменной `$(subs)` («сеанс разоблачения магии» будет ниже):

```
subs=$(if $(filter $@,$(list)),по-особому,обычным образом)
```

в итоге получится такой файл:

```
srcs=a1.src a2.src a3.src a4.src
results=$(srcs:.src=.res)
list=a2.res a3.res
subs=$(if $(filter $@,$(list)),по-особому,обычным образом)
all: $(results)
%.res: %.src
  @echo 'собираем $@ из $< $(subs)'
```

из которого при интерпретации получится такой вывод:

```
$ make
собираем a1.res из a1.src обычным образом
собираем a2.res из a2.src по-особому
собираем a3.res из a3.src по-особому
собираем a4.res из a4.src обычным образом
```

---

#### сеанс разоблачения магии

- [функция](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Functions.html#Conditional-Functions) `$(if выражение,если да,если нет)` (вариант без «если нет»: `$(if выражение,если да)` проверяет «выражение» на пустоту: если не пустое, то возвращает «если да», иначе — «если нет» (или ничего в варианте без «если нет»)
- [функция](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#index-filter) `$(filter набор слов,текст)` возвращает все слова из «набора слов», которые встречаются в «тексте» (если ни одно не встретилось, вернёт пустую строку).
- все автоматические переменные можно увидеть в [списке функций, переменных и директив](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Name-Index.html#Name-Index) (в частности, использованные выше [`$@`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#index-_0024_0040) и [`$<`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#index-_0024_003c)).